# Templating text document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to create script for creating contracts. For this will be in 'Template File which is going to be text file on gDrive' example:

```
Client's VAT: $VAT
Client's Name: $Clients_name
```

How do I get this file content ( getBody(), which works only on Document Types, but you are not able to access Document instance, because all possibilities I've found lead me to File instance.. )

My target is to get exact copy of 'Template File' and go through him and change words starting with dollar, changing them by values from HTTP request. ( this part is already done. )

**EDIT:**

you might be interested about my try ( or it can help someone )

```
function createContract(obj)
{
  const templateName = "RC - Contract Template";
  const templateFile = getTemplate(templateName);
  const templateText = templateFile.getAs("plain/text");
  const file = DocumentApp.create(obj.filename);
  const body = file.getBody();
  const url = file.getUrl();

  body.insertParagraph(0, templateText);

  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(url);
}
```

*Note:* getTemplate() is function going through all files and returning instance of File with name 'RC - Contract Template'

Comment: Welcome. On this site it's encouraged that askers answer their own question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. I've said I haven't got find out any possibility. This  means there is no way to create file based on template ?

Comment: Do you mean that your solution isn't a solution?

Comment: Oh, I think there is misunderstanding. By "my solution" i tried to show up how am I trying to figure it out. But exactly as u say, it is NOT a solution. 

Because "templateFile" returns File instance and u cannot get an text content. 
"templateText" is just an error by " you cannot change content-type..."

PS: already changed to "try"

Comment: I did, I used "templateFile.getBlob()" and then "templateBlob.getDataAsString()", but my file contains these: "~or��~��?�  >�����������$   /h  RK����{G�  �  pM��zy]� s �� ��3k˫ {?� ". Why ? It's file header? How Do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I've found out, that google has a big difference  between "File", "Document", etc etc.

If someone gets in same situation, this is my way to get Content of file, when you know only name:

```
function getTemplateId(filename) {
  const files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getName() == filename) return file.getId();
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Required template: " + filename + " does not exists!");
}
```

---

Note:Moved Solution posted by OP from question: